# ISelection -- How can I get ClassLoader for the selected class in the navigator

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, classloader, eclipse-jdt, urlclassloader

I am new to Eclipse plugin development, and I am trying to develop a plugin where I am required to load a class which is selected in the Navigator.

Can you please instruct me how can I load a class or create a classloader from eclipse plugin, to load a class in the eclipse workbench which is using my plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Gillani

Comment: Are these classes already part of an Eclipse plugin, or are these classes external all installed plugins?

Comment: no these classes are not the part of the plugin, rather they are the classes from a user project, who is developing using my plugin, he/she selects a class in the navigator view of Eclipse, in response my plugin gets a call and I get the selected class as ISelection object of the plugin action. I want to load the selected class in my plugin, because I want to get the names of the setter methods of the selected class.

Comment: That complicates things a little bit, but I may have a solution for you.

Comment: Wait...I just answered the question, but then I reread what you wrote.  All you want to do is find out what the setter methods are?  If so, wouldn't you be better off parsing the text of the class or using a class file reader instead of class loading?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a URLClassLoader.  You may want it to be parented or not, depending on your security concerns.  If parented by an OSGi bundle class loader, then the user will have access to all of the classes in that particular bundle and this may be a back door to the user getting runtime access to the entire Eclipse platform (and access the plugin registry and the OSGi services, etc).  The user can also call `System.exit()`.  This may not be a problem on a single user system, but it is something to think about, especially if the user may be downloading unverified scripts from the internet.

That being said, you need to do something like this:

1. Instantiate a URLClassLoader and add the URLs of the directories containing the class files you will want to load.
2. if you want the classes to have access to the Eclipse runtime, then set the parent loader to be 
   `((BundleHost) Activator.getBundleContext().getBundle()).getLoaderProxy().getBundleLoader()`
3. Add all of the directories corresponding to URLs where the user can load classes from.  But, you must include all dependencies in order to load the classes.
4. This should be enough to load the classes you require.

Comment: thanks Andrew,

I agree to you in that I am required a URLClassLoader. I am trying to create one simple poc like this:

URL[] urls = {new URL("file:/F:\\dao\\bin\\com\\badge\\dao\\impl\\")};
    
ClassLoader parentClassLoader = project.getClass().getClassLoader();
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, parentClassLoader);
    
    
selectedClass = classLoader.loadClass("BadgeDaoImpl");

Regards
Gillani

Comment: And what happens when you try to load your class this way?